# Как правильно: табель постам или табель постов?

Tags: грамматика

Табель постам или табель постов - как правильно?

Answer (score 1):

**Табель постам** — один из документов, регламентирующих организацию и несение службы караулом. В табеле постам часовому указываются объекты охраны и обороны на каждом посту, обязанности с учетом особенностей поста и конкретных условий несения на нем службы и т.д. [Табель постам | academic.ru](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/sea/14794/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C)